# Disable table mode in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I use org mode to write notebooks for my research. I often put equation on line of their own, using `M-o M-s` to center the equation.

However, when I have an equation like

```
|a+b| ≤ |a| + |b|
```

the leading `|` character makes org enter in tabular mode. How can I disable this effect ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [literal example](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html#Literal-examples). Like this:

```
Here is my important equation:
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
|a+b| ≤ |a| + |b|
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

A shorthand using a colon following one or more spaces also works:

```
Here is my important equation:
   : |a+b| ≤ |a| + |b|
Isn't it nice.
```

Literal examples are usually written in monospace and indented when exported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `org-enable-table-editor` to nil (using `(setq org-enable-table-editor nil)`)? This should do what you want.

This code (added to you `init.el`) should make the change permanent:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook
            (lambda () (setq org-enable-table-editor nil)  )))
```

Comment: Hm, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. I pasted the code in my init file (.emacs) and tried to change the value of the variable in the session to no avail. The | still triggers a table font.

Comment: The coloring may still appear, but your command should still work.

Comment: I have confirmed that `M-o M-s` does indeed work for me, even though the text is still colored.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why I talked about `M-o M-s`, it's irrelevant, and it was already working before. The problem is more with 1. it's colored, and 2. the font is not the same (it's bigger).

Comment: @Literal: Please edit/update your question, or post a new question.

Comment: Changing the font/coloring requires customizing the `face`, which you can customize directly using `M-x customize-group RET org-appearance RET`. What you want to do will depend on your specific configuration.

Comment: Specifically, you want to customize the `org-table` face. One approach is to remap that face to the default face: `(add-to-list 'face-remapping-alist '(org-table . default))`. The remapping list is buffer-local, so you can write a command to toggle this or perhaps put it in an org-mode-hook.